# Cannot close window opener in webview Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web, flutter-web

I use web view to convert my website into the android app using flutter. From the website, I have window.opener to display update form and the window have two buttons, “update” and “back”.

It display good and update successfully. However, it unable to close when clicking “back”.

How can I view the window and back after do the task by using webview? I have read somewhere which use InAppWebView but do not know to apply it.

Please help me, I am very beginner in Flutter.

Comment: Hello, may I ask what Plugin do you use to show the Webview in your App? By any chance can you also clarify in a few short sentences what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use InAppWebView here is an exemple to help you with your problem:
https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/basic-usage/

just copy the code and try it.

Comment: link not working (404)